# Custom Confirm Box Media Device

Tags: android, html, css, media, confirm

I have it to where people must accept the terms of use in my website before they can use it. There is a dialog "Custom Confirm Box" that shows up when you start it to ask if you'd like to accept the terms. While this box shows perfectly on pc and tablets, I can't get it for phones :(, I've tried the method

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width:768px)   {
#dialogbox {
    height:100px;
    width:225px;
}}
```

but just cant seem to figure it out :/ Please help!
This is coded in "CSS/HTML/JavaScript".

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of the question, the dialogue box is a custom div. For that, it may be a case of the fact that the mobile browser does not have the same compatibility that a desktop browser might have.

For mobiles, you could use a standard alert box from JavaScript `alert('foo');` or look into a JavaScript plugin such as JQuery UI which offers better dialogue box support in viewports and different browsers.

Hopefully some of that helps:)